# Jquery.post's fetch analog

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I've tried to move from a jQuery.post to a default functionality called `fetch` for making requests. I've realized, that queries which looks the same has different behaviour.

**jQuery.post**:

```
jQuery.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/core/comment/add',
    data: {
        type: "article",
        identity: 1931,
        body: "Some stuff"
    }
}).done(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

**fetch**:

```
fetch('/core/comment/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        type: "article",
        identity: 1931,
        body: "Some stuff"
    })
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

In `jQuery.post` case everything works good, but `fetch` returns me a status of 404. I've also tried to add `credentials: 'same-origin'` option, tried to send data w/o `JSON.stringify` and headers, but nothing changed - $_POST is empty.
So what is difference and how to achieve the same behaviour?

Comment: If you go into the Network pane of your browser devtools and reload and inspect both requests, what differences do you see? Is the Content-Type value the same? Is the response body the same? Is the response body of the jQuery request shown there actually JSON?

Comment: What is `i.core.request.fetchLocal(…)`? What might it be doing differently from just calling the native `fetch(…)` method directly? Have you tried the same request with just the native `fetch(…)` method instead of `i.core.request.fetchLocal(…)`?

Comment: i.core.fetchLocal just check `/` symbol is first of url and return the same fetch. I think, I will edit this post to make not people missunderstand.

Comment: @sideshowbarker network tool showed the difference (https://pastebin.com/yw9xj5ZD). jQuery.post sends data as Form Data and fetch as Request payload. Response content-type different because 404 sends a html page.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yw9xj5ZD indicates jQuery is sending the data as 'tapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded'; see the answer below for how to do that with the Fetch API. As far as why the 'application/json' fetch request doesn’t work as expected, I guess it’s because the backend doesn’t expect to receive 'application/json' but expects 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' data instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pastebin.com/yw9xj5ZD shows `jQuery.post` sent `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, so to do the same thing with the Fetch API, use the following code:

```
fetch('/core/comment/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: "type=article&identity=1931&body=Some stuff"
    })
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

That is:

- change the `Content-Type` request-header value to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- use a string for the `body`, in the form `type=article&identity=1931&body=Some stuff`

Comment: Well, what if I need to send array? For example `{subject:{type:"article",identity:1931}, body: "Some stuff"}`? Should I make JSON of each array and then urlencode that? I impressed that there's no clean and simple way to send array or json w/o urlencoding.

Comment: What does jQuery.post do in the case where you send data like `{subject:{type:"article",identity:1931}, body: "Some stuff"}`? I suspect it may change the content-type to application/json in that case. Have you tried giving that data to jQuery.post for a request to that server? I expect if you do, you would get a 404 just like you did for the fetch application/json request.

Comment: As far as the clean and simple way to send json, the way to do that is to just use content-type: application/json. But it appears that particular backend doesn’t expect to get data posted as application/json…

Comment: ofc I will get an error in that way, because I've asked about probability of doing that, it was not implemented in that case. It doen't change content-type and urlencoded like that: `fake[a]:5 fake[b]:6`.

Comment: Found an instresting part: `application/json` request payload not in $_POST or $_REQUEST variables, but in file located at "php://input", so you could get clear JSON data like that: `$request = file_get_contents("php://input")` and than `json_decode($request, true)` for decode it.